# GCP: Get old state of a table

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a table in GCP (BigQuery) that is overwritten every day with data from an external source. Is there any way to view the state of the table at a point in the past? The following code (from https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/time-travel):

```
SELECT *
FROM `mydataset.mytable`
  FOR SYSTEM_TIME AS OF TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR);
```

produces results just for the case when the "interval" is younger than the time when the table was last modified.

**EDIT:** It looks like the maximum time travel window is 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

I used the console since it was easier to manage and view.

In order to view the past state of your BigQuery table, you can hover to `PERSONAL HISTORY` to display the information of your recent jobs or to `PROJECT HISTORY` to display the recent jobs in your project.

[image]

After overwriting your query, you can notice that it has been executed, and per execution has a `Job ID`. If you specifically know the Job ID of the past table that you want to view, you can filter it. You can also view the `Query job details` when you click the 3 vertical dots, and from there you can see the state of the table with its specific timestamp and other essential details.

[image]